# Verifying struct keys presence in tests

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

```
assert Contract.fetch(contract: valid_address) == %Contract{
         contract: "0x3D29Aa78fB558F84112bbC48a84F371147A920C9",
         name: "bla",
         price: nil,
         price_bnb: nil,
         call_id: 7,
         symbol: nil,
         transactions: []
       }
```

this test passes, however the `Contract` struct includes more keys than listed here in the test, how can I make this test fail if not all keys are provided?

Comment: What do you mean by "not provided"? Do you mean `nil`? Or do you mean "not present on the struct". Because keys are _always_ present on the struct.

Answer (score 0):

Use [pattern matching](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.11.4/lib/ex_unit/lib/ex_unit/assertions.ex#L107-L129) in [`ExUnit.Assertions.assert/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Assertions.html#assert/1) instead of equality check.

```elixir
assert %Contract{
         contract: "0x3D29" <> _,
         name: "bla",
       } = Contract.fetch(contract: valid_address)
```

Comment: thanks, but still if I miss specifying one key on the left side the test passes

Comment: I do not follow. Structs are not maps, you cannot “miss” a key. If not specified, it contains the default value and still plays in pattern-matching.